# Deploy application in facebook

Tags: facebook, deployment, spring-social

I am programming an application that will be integrated in Facebook canvas and I am using Spring Social to communicate with Facebook. The application uses Facebook data to retrieve users data  and Open graph to publish an activity.  I have tested the app using my localhost tomcat server but I wonder if there is a way to deploy my app at Facebook. I don't own a domain and I want to deploy this application in Facebook. I have tested the Iframe but it seems that it supports only static HTML code, not an java application. The only way is to deploy it in a public domain and than link it at the app dashboard. 
It seems odd that people upload an enormous amount of photos, videos, notes in your platform and I didn't find a way to upload an application.

Is it possible from you to provide me with some information concerning this problem that I have encountered?
Will Facebook offer sometime sooner a way for its developers do host their application in its platform?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook provide some hosting but not in Java. AFAIK Ruby, Python and PHP are supported. You can check under you app's Basic Info section.